# Visual Basic how to stop an event after MsgBox is shown

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I want to make sure that the user has checked one of my 3 checkboxes before my furthur process, thus I created the function below and generate a Msg if they didn't checked anything. the issue is the process still carries on after the msg box. So is there any way to stop this event after this particular msgbox is shown?

```
Private Sub btnPay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPay.Click
        If chkbNotes.Checked = True Then
            conn.Open()
            sql = "UPDATE Order SET payment_method_id = 1 WHERE Id = '" + FoodMenu.OrderID + "';"
            cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Else
            If chkbCreditCard.Checked = True Then
                conn.Open()
                sql = "UPDATE Order SET payment_method_id = 2 WHERE Id = '" + FoodMenu.OrderID + "';"
                cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Else
                If chkbEwallet.Checked = True Then
                    conn.Open()
                    sql = "UPDATE Order SET payment_method_id = 2 WHERE Id = '" + FoodMenu.OrderID + "';"
                    cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Else
                    MsgBox("Please choose 1 Payment Method", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
                End If
            End If
        End If
        Dim Amount As String
        Amount = InputBox("Enter Paying Amount (EX:100.00)", "Amount")
        If (IsNumeric(Amount)) = True Then
        .
        .
        .
```

Comment: you can use one `return`

Comment: That's not an event. It's a method. Event handlers are just methods that get executed when an event is raised. You exit this method in exactly the same way as you would exit any other method.

Comment: Don't nest `If...Else` statements like that. That should be a single `If...ElseIf...ElseIf...Else` block.

Comment: Also, you really need to learn the DRY principle: Don't Repeat Yourself. You have lots of repeated code in there and that's bad. The only thing that changes in each case is the payment method so all you need to do in each case is set a single variable for that. You then execute the query at the end, writing the code to do that once only.

Comment: Rather than using checkboxes maybe you could use a group of radio buttons? With checkboxes, more than one could accidentally be checked. With 3 radio buttons in a group box, only one can be chosen at a time.In fact add a 4th button for no selection and set that one as the default selection and then check that it isn't  the one chosen in your event handler

Comment: What I know for the query the other 2 checkboxes will reappear again if you unchecked the checked textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what your code ought to look like:

```vb
Private Sub btnPay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPay.Click
    Dim paymentMethodId As Integer

    If chkbNotes.Checked Then
        paymentMethodId = 1
    ElseIf chkbCreditCard.Checked Then
        paymentMethodId = 2
    ElseIf chkbEwallet.Checked Then
        paymentMethodId = 3
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please choose 1 Payment Method", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

        Return
    End If

    sql = "UPDATE Order SET payment_method_id = @PaymentMethodId WHERE Id = @Id"
    cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, conn)

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@PaymentMethodId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = paymentMethodId
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = FoodMenu.OrderID

    conn.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

I have taken the liberty of assuming that the payemtn method ID should be 3 in the third case rather than 2, which you were using in your original code.

I would also recommend changing your ADO.NEt code as it appears that you are reusing connection and command objects. You should just create and destroy them where and when you need them.

Comment: I think the message box syntax should be like this `MessageBox.Show("Please choose 1 Payment Method", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)`. because the code you given has syntax error. Just my humble opinion.

Comment: You are correct. I copied that from the WPF documentation by mistake. The code has been fixed.

Comment: Nit picking, just to mention that `Exit Sub` would be "correct" way ;)

Comment: @Fabio, nope. As far as I'm aware, there's actually no difference between the two in the compiled code. I can't recall where exactly but I read in the Microsoft documentation a long time ago that `Return` was preferred. `Exit Sub` is probably the preference of those with a VB6 background but it is a VB-specific thing and those coming from other languages would likely prefer `Return`, e.g. all C# methods are functions and only `return` is available. I would suggest that, whatever you do, make sure you are consistent. As I never use `Exit Function`, I never use `Exit Sub`. Either is as correct.

Comment: `Exit Sub` is preference for those who write vb.net. As you said every team choose own consistent style. That why I mentioned "nit picking" and added a smily face ;)